# Problem Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: SubTaskOne

Tags: typescript, export, vite

I am building a Site that can handle Users and Tasks.
Now that I want to test the Tasks I get this error.
I want to make a list of different tasks
But I cant seem to import them properly.

When I autoImport from the IDE it does not help either.

This is my main.ts

```
import {SubTask,Task,SubTaskOne} from "./Task/Task";


const task1 = new Task('ersterTask')
const task2 = new Task('zweiterTask')
const task3 = new SubTask("subTask1", task1)
const task4 = new SubTaskOne("subTask2", task2, 1)

const tasks = [task1, task2, task3, task4];
tasks.forEach(task =>{
    task.printTask
})


this is my Task.ts file

    
export interface ITask{
    taskName: string;
    printTask():void
}

export class Task implements ITask{
    constructor(taskName: string) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
    }
    taskName: string;
    printTask() {
        console.log(this.taskName);
    }
}

export class SubTask extends Task implements ITask {
    parentTask: Task;
    constructor(taskName: string, parentTask: Task) {
        super(taskName);
        this.taskName = taskName;
        this.parentTask = parentTask;
    }
    printTask() {
        super.printTask();
        console.log(this.parentTask);
    }
}

export class SubTaskOne extends SubTask implements ITask {
    taskId : number;
    constructor(taskName: string, parentTask: Task, taskId: number) {
        super(taskName, parentTask);
        this.taskName = taskName;
        this.parentTask = parentTask;
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }
    printTask() {
        super.printTask()
        console.log(this.taskId);
    }
}
```

When I execute i get this:

```
    'Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: SubTaskOne'
```

I am using typescript and Vite

this is my package.json:

```
    {
   "name": "tdd",
   "private": true,
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "type": "module",
   "scripts": {
      "dev": "vite",
      "build": "tsc && vite build",
      "preview": "vite preview",
      "test": "jest"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
      "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.3",
      "jest": "^29.6.1",
      "jest-localstorage-mock": "^2.4.26",
      "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
      "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
      "typeorm": "^0.3.17",
      "typescript": "4.5.2",
      "vite": "^4.4.0",
      "ts-node": "10.7.0",
      "@types/node": "^16.11.10"
   },
   "jest": {
      "preset": "ts-jest",
      "testEnvironment": "node",
      "transform": {
         "node_modules/variables/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "ts-jest"
      },
      "transformIgnorePatterns": [
         "node_modules/(?!variables/.*)"
      ],
      "resetMocks": false,
      "setupFiles": [
         "jest-localstorage-mock"
      ]
    },
     "dependencies": {
      "axios": "^1.4.0",
      "typeorm": "0.3.17",
      "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
      "pg": "^8.4.0",
      "express": "^4.17.2",
      "body-parser": "^1.19.1"
       }
    }
```

edit: even after putting the tasks in different files it did not work
import looks like this now:

```
import {Task as Task} from "./Task/Task";
import {SubTask} from "./Task/SubTask";
import {SubTaskOne} from "./Task/SubTaskOne";
```